# UICollectionViewCell issue with generics cell getter function

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uicollectionview, extension-methods

i wrote an extension class for uitableview

```
extension UITableView {

    func register(_ cellsName : String)
    {
        self.register(UINib.init(nibName: cellsName, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellsName)
    }

    func cell<T>(for index: IndexPath) -> T where T: UITableViewCell {
        if let dict = value(forKey: "_nibMap") as? [String: UINib],dict.keys.contains(String(describing: T.self)) { } else {
            register(String(describing: T.self))
        }
        return self.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: T.self), for: index) as! T
    }
}
```

and i would do

```
let tempCell: UITempCell = tableview.cell(indexPath)
```

which works with no issue...

but in case of ui collection view

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func register(_ cellsName : String)
    {
        self.register(UINib.init(nibName: cellsName, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellsName)
    }

    func cell<T>(for index: IndexPath) -> T where T: UICollectionViewCell {
        if let dict = value(forKey: "_nibMap") as? [String: UINib],dict.keys.contains(String(describing: T.self)) { } else {
            register(String(describing: T.self))
        }
       return self.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: T.self), for: index) as! T
    }
}
```

i get a warning saying

> Cast from 'UICollectionViewCell' to unrelated type 'T' always fails

and if i tries to use this function for

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

xcode give error saying

> Type 'UILocationDetailsViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

**Update:**
it was my mistake i had a tableview cell with name UICollectionViewCell so extension was linking my cell instead of original class

Comment: did you implement both numberOfRows & cellForItem ?

Comment: yes and solved...sorry my mistake and thank you for the reply